# Docker pull from artifactory fails with credentials issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifactory

I have a Jenkins job on a remote environment where I use docker to pull down an image (`microsoft/aspnetcore-build/2.0.0`) from a local Artifactory repo, but the docker pull fails with - 'unknown: Forbidden', yet other jobs sharing the same Artifactory credentials do not fail.
The docker pull seems to proceed only when attempted from my local or any other machine, and then the job is kicked off manually on Jenkins. There are multiple retries for each image layer and subsequently it fails with -

> 'unknown: Rejected artifact download request: User xyz is not
>   permitted to deploy 'microsoft/aspnetcore-build/2.0.0'.

Comment: Does the xyz user has deploy permission on the remote Docker repository in Artifactory?

Comment: yes the use has deploy permissions. The job now works ie docker pulls successfuly, but without any configuration changes , this issue occurred for about 3days nonstop, and suddenly disappeared, the same sequence of events happened with a previous job.

Answer (score 0):

try add `docker login -u $DOCKER_USER  -p $DOCKER_PW $DOCKER_URL` to make sure you already loggin