# Why is Artifactory returning a 403 for all users when called from gradle artifactory plugin?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, http-status-code-403

Relevant setup information: gradle 4+, relatively new installation of Artifactory (Pro 6+), artifactory gradle plugin version 4+

When attempting to run the build command on a local development environment in both Eclipse Photon and IntelliJ (late 2017 version), I run into dozens and dozens of 403 errors when making a HEAD request for dependencies. But, if I login to Artifactory through a web browser as the user that gradle is using and go to the exact same URL, it has no problem reaching the resource that gradle failed to reach. The problem occurs with every user on Artifactory, even one with admin privileges. The jars I'm looking for are part of a virtual repository with dependencies both internal to the artifactory installation and external. Finally, the build used to work just fine a month ago, and nothing I can think of has changed to permissions.

tl;dr **only when logging in from gradle and using Artifactory plugin, a virtual Artifactory repo returns 403 errors on nearly every dependency for every user**

This question: [Docker pull from artifactory fails with credentials issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150614/docker-pull-from-artifactory-fails-with-credentials-issue) seemed close, but is using docker+jenkins (I'm not) and has no answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I finally dug into the system logs, I found many lines like this one: "Rejected artifact download request: User XYZ is not permitted to deploy 'SOME JAR' into 'SOME CACHE JAR'"

It appears that users must have DEPLOY permissions in order to download an artifact that will be cached (behavior of virtuals/remotes.) This may also explain why the build used to work - the cached jars wouldn't have needed updates a month ago when I'd just added the remote and downloaded everything.

Adding deploy permissions to my user for the relevant repositories fixed the issue.